# How to fix 'object of type 'float' has no len()' while automating filling webform in Python with Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, selenium, floating-point

I am trying to automate a form filling action, and I already have Selenium imported and running. I am able to execute the code on the first iteration, but for the second iteration, the following error message occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#63>", line 4, in <module>
    ans_box.send_keys(ans)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 478, in send_keys
    {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/utils.py", line 150, in keys_to_typing
    for i in range(len(val)):
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

```
i = 0
while i<1:
    ans_box = browser.find_element_by_name('AnSwEr0001')
    ans_box.send_keys(i)
    i=i+0.0001
    submit_box = browser.find_element_by_name('submitAnswers')
    submit_box.click()
```

Would greatly appreciate help with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In Selenium docs:
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html

```
 send_keys(*value)[source]
    Simulates typing into the element.
    Args :  
        value - A string for typing, or setting form fields. For setting file inputs, this could be a local file path.
```

You need to give string to send_keys()

```
ans_box.send_keys(str(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

...implies that you have passed a **float** value within `send_keys()` method.

---

### Analysis

In the first iteration *value* of **i** is `0` an is of type `int`. But in the next iteration *value* of **i** is `0.0001` and is of type `float`. This can be demonstrated with an example as follows:

- Sample Code:

  ```
  browser.get("https://www.google.com/")
  i = 0
  print(type(i))
  while i<1:
      ans_box = browser.find_element_by_name('q')
      ans_box.clear()
      ans_box.send_keys(i)
      i=i+0.0001
      print(type(i))
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  <class 'int'>
  <class 'float'>
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\AtechM_03\LearnAutmation\PythonProject\Stackoverflow\test.py", line 14, in <module>
      ans_box.send_keys(i)
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 478, in send_keys
      {'text': "".join(keys_to_typing(value)),
    File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\utils.py", line 150, in keys_to_typing
      for i in range(len(val)):
  TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
  ```

But, [send_keys(*value)](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.send_keys) accepts a `string` as an argument.

---

### Solution

You need to convert the `float` datatype into `string` to be able to pass through `send_keys()` as follows:

```
i = 0
while i<1:
    ans_box = browser.find_element_by_name('AnSwEr0001')
    ans_box.send_keys(repr(i))
    i=i+0.0001
    submit_box = browser.find_element_by_name('submitAnswers')
    submit_box.click()
```